# How return a value from an asynchronous function with SQLite3 and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to make a small database using SQLite3 for my discord bot (on node.js), and I'd like to make a function that updates the database with provided values (this part works) or return a value of the database.

My problème is here, the returned value is always undefined...

I have understood that SQLite3 commands are asynchronous so all the functions become asynchronous, but how I can make sure that the returned value be no longer undefined?

Here is my code :

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const dbname = 'dbStocks';

module.exports = function gestionBDD(update, nomArticle, quantitéArticle) {
 console.log('1 ' + quantitéArticle);

 let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbname, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Démarrage de ' + dbname);
 });

 db.serialize(() => {
  nomArticle = '"' + nomArticle + '"';

  if (update) {
   //Si update est true : maj des quantités via le tableau articles

   db.run(
    `UPDATE stocks
                SET Quantité = (` +
     quantitéArticle +
     `)
                WHERE Article = (` +
     nomArticle +
     `)`
   );
  } else if (!update) {
   db.each(
    `SELECT Quantité FROM stocks WHERE Article  = (` + nomArticle + `)`,
    (err, data) => {
     console.log('2 ' + data.Quantité);
     return data.Quantité;
    }
   );
  }

  console.log('4 ' + quantitéArticle);
  db.close((err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('Arrêt de ' + dbname);
  });
 });
};
```

And I get this result:

```
1 undefined
4 undefined
3 undefined
Démarrage de dbStocks
2 500
Arrêt de dbStocks
```

(the `3 undefined` is a `console.log()` in my `index.js` where my function `gestionBDD` is call)

Answer (score 4):

You can return a promise that can get resolved later for function return like this:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 db.run(`query statement here`, (err, row) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  resolve(row);
 });
});
```

Writing this at the top of the function to make it async function. when calling the function use ether `await` or `then` to get a return result data.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the resolve() function exactly ?
Is it the function I have to use to get a return result data ?

I have difficulties with this system of async function and promise...

Comment: The resolve() function is used to return data asynchronously and yes you have to use it to get data. The reject function is used to to return errors or failed messages and datas.